# Different options depending on QRadioButton

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qwidget

I have a Qt Designer form (widget), that includes N radio buttons. And i want to see different options (QGroupBox, etc) depending on selected button in the same widget. What is the right way to solve this problem?

Of course, i can place all boxes in widget and change their visibility depending on selected radio button, but that is not perfect i'm sure.

Comment: I guess you want to use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) is what you're looking for.

Put your [radio buttons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html) into a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), then connect [QButtonGroup::buttonClicked(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked-1) to [QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop).